# How to make bins with the size 100 for a start and end numbers using awk?

Tags: shell, awk

**Input File 1**

```
NM_75 X + 3000623
NM_47 X - 3000333
NM_60 X + 3000132
NM_70 X - 3000258
```

How to get the start and end coordinates at -1500 and +1500 for the each one in the 4th field and make bins with the size of 100 using awk?

**output should be**

```
start coordinate -1500+3000623= 2999123
end coordinate    3000623+1500= 3002123
```

now from the range of 2999123-3002123, have to make bins with the size 100 i.e., 3000/100 total 30 bins likewise for each other coordinates in the 4th field.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give required output as well?

Comment: I have updated my question with desired output. plz check it..

Comment: The third field is a sing of the 4th field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how those "bins" should be presented, but a quick hack for the base problem:

```
cat >infile <<XXX
NM_75 X + 3000623
NM_47 X - 3000333
NM_60 X + 3000132
NM_70 X - 3000258
XXX

awk '{print "start coordinate -1500+"$4"="$4-1500;
  for(i=-1400; i<1500; i+=100) print $1,$2,$3,$4+i
  print "end coordinate    "$4"+1500="$4+1500}' infile
```

Output:

```
start coordinate -1500+3000623=2999123
NM_75 X + 2999223
NM_75 X + 2999323
...
NM_75 X + 3001923
NM_75 X + 3002023
end coordinate    3000623+1500=3002123
start coordinate -1500+3000333=2998833
NM_47 X - 2998933
NM_47 X - 2999033
...
NM_47 X - 3001633
NM_47 X - 3001733
end coordinate    3000333+1500=3001833
start coordinate -1500+3000132=2998632
NM_60 X + 2998732
NM_60 X + 2998832
...
NM_60 X + 3001432
NM_60 X + 3001532
end coordinate    3000132+1500=3001632
start coordinate -1500+3000258=2998758
NM_70 X - 2998858
NM_70 X - 2998958
...
NM_70 X - 3001558
NM_70 X - 3001658
end coordinate    3000258+1500=3001758
```

Same in pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
while read x y z n; do
  printf "start coordinate -1500+%7d=%7d\n" $n $((n-1500))
  for((i=-1400;i<1500;i+=100));{ printf "%s %s %s %d\n" $x $y $z $((n+i));}
  printf "end coordinate    %7d+1500=%7d\n" $n $((n+1500))
done <infile
```

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is much faster for large files.

Qs:

- Is the 3rd field is a sign of the 4th field?
- How the "bins" should be presented?

Comment: Thanks True... and 1st field represents the name of a particular gene sequence. Now have to make a matrix with 1st field as columns, bins as rows.                                                    .    bin1 bin2......bin30                                         gene1                                                               gene2                                                         .....                                                          genex

Comment: @SriNagesh: If You write the expected output into your Q then I can tailor my answer. If I understood well You need a matrix as an output. The row header is the `bin##` and column header is the first row in the input file. And each column contains numbers between (4th field-1500) and (4th field+1500). Am I right? But if you need to run from -1500 to 1500 it is 31 bins, not 30. Am I missing something?